# connect ECCONREFUSED ::1:50106

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a discord bot with Node.js and erela.js, but when I try to get the server that handles erela on, it shows me this error:

```
 A node error occured: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:50106
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367157+00:00 app[worker.1]: events.js:287
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367175+00:00 app[worker.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367176+00:00 app[worker.1]:       ^
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367176+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367177+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:50106
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367178+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367179+00:00 app[worker.1]: Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367179+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:554:15)
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367179+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:310:20)
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367180+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367181+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367181+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367181+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367182+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367185+00:00 app[worker.1]:   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367185+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367185+00:00 app[worker.1]:   syscall: 'connect',
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367186+00:00 app[worker.1]:   address: '::1',
2020-05-01T21:23:19.367186+00:00 app[worker.1]:   port: 50106
```

The index.js code is:

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const bot = new discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});
const prefix = "."
const token = process.env.token;
const { ErelaClient } = require('erela.js');

function server () {
  require ("./server.js");
}


// When bot ready
bot.on("ready", async () => {
server(); 
  bot.music = new ErelaClient(bot, [
    {
      host: process.env.HOST,
      port: process.env.PORT,
      password: process.env.PASSWORD
    }
  ]);  
  bot.music.on("nodeConnect", node => console.log("New node connected, music is now working on the bot!"));
bot.music.on("nodeError", (node, error) =>  console.log(`A node error occured: ${error.message}`));
```

And the server.js code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(7000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 7000, so erela will work!');
 });
```

I don't know why it's happening. If someone has an answer for this. I'd be grateful

Comment: Hard to tell without more info about your app and relevant source code. Are you starting something on port 50106?

Comment: No, on port 7000. Sorry but I forgot to send the index.js code. I'll send it in a sec

Comment: Express is running on :7000, what's `process.env.PORT`? Also, strange to see a function just calling require. What's the reason behind this?

Comment: process.env.PORT is declared in my bot hosting service, it's a config var, and it's 7000. And the function was just to call server.js, I couldn't get any other way so I just used that

Comment: Whay port is your discord bot running?

Comment: I don't know, Heroku (the app that is hosting my bot) doesn't show that information

Comment: So you are running discord as well as this app in heroku?

Comment: First thing you should do is to move the require out of that function. That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Running 2 processes on the same port is going to cause issues. You can export app in `server.js` and require it in `index`.

Comment: @AndreasMoldskred I have seen this pattern. This is popular in boilerplate repos. This is not causing the problems.

Comment: Hmm, seems like a rather bad way to require stuff. But fair enough. By the look of his dependency https://github.com/WarHammer414/erela.js it looks like the right way of listning for ready is using .once instead on on

Comment: The problem here is `process.env.port` should be his discord bot's port.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two servers running on the same PC, you should enable CORS to allow communications between both of them.

Add in the server.js file:

```
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```

Also, install in CLI:

```
npm install cors
```

[CORS npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Hi, did this in the server.js, but it still shows the ECONREFUSED error.

Comment: You should add it to the server which is receiving the request.